# Extending bit twiddling hack for Log_2 to 64 bit

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, 32bit-64bit

I've implemented the code [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup) in C# to get the MSB of an int. I'm not certain what I need to do with the log reference table and the main code to extend the code to 64 bit.

The only thing the text says is it will take 2 more CPU ops, so I deduce the change is minor.

Comment: It is tagged C, but you are using C#?

Comment: The source code is C. I will convert to C#. I'm not asking someone to do this for me... just how do I implement the C in 64 bit (in C).

Comment: Assuming you are on a kind of x86 architecture, I would just use the bsr instruction. In gcc it is available as __builtin_clzll(). This calculates the logarithm with one instruction... Unfortunatly I don't know how you could translate it to C#.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly legit question.

Comment: bsr would be perfect. I wonder why MS didn't implement some of these lower level commands into C#. This is the third time I've encountered needing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table does not need to be changed.  One more level of `if()` is needed:

```
if (ttt = v >> 32)
{
    if (tt = ttt >> 16)
         r = (t = tt >> 8) ? 56 + LogTable256[t] : 48 + LogTable256[tt]
    else
         r = (t = ttt >> 8) ? 40 + LogTable256[t] : 32 + LogTable256[ttt]
}
else
{
    if (tt = v >> 16)
        r = (t = tt >> 8) ? 24 + LogTable256[t] : 16 + LogTable256[tt];
    else 
        r = (t = v >> 8) ? 8 + LogTable256[t] : LogTable256[v];
}
```